# Boot Camp Windows 7 Ultimate Black Screen Problem

Tags: mac, boot-camp

I have burned on disk "Windows 7 Ultimate.iso" and I was installed it.
Everything had worked good until the windows showed Black Screen ( in the Complete Installation part ). I tried two downloads from different websites and it show the same problem.

I'll be thankful for help.

Before the installation of the windows 7, its ask this question:

[image]

Comment: By the way, before the installation of the windows 7, its ask this question: ![enter image description here][1] 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hMbwa.jpg

What it is?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel - If you look at the Windows 7 FAQ from Apple, there are some bluetooth issues that might be causing the black screen for two iMac models.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3986

Once you have exhausted all the mac articles and are certain you have all the correct software, you might need to ask on a forum with more windows installer specific knowledge.

In general - if you get the installer running, then the Mac side of BootCamp is working. I'm not a big user of the windows sites at SE - so you might flag this for a moderator to transfer this to another associated site where more people have experience with troubleshooting the windows 7 installer process.

You might also cross post on whatever other site is best and link back here since you might actually need answers from both areas of expertise to solve your specific issue.

Best of luck!

Comment: Which forum?

* By the way, where can I update my Boot Camp to 3.1+? ( For Mac )